# colorchange animation for background

Tags: css, animation

I Want to change background color slowly and use this code in css file:

```
body {
margin-top:60px;
font-family: sans-serif;
animation: colorchange 50s;
-webkit-animation: colorchange 50s;
     }

@keyframes colorchange{
    0%   {background: #FFCCff;}
   25%  {background: #FFFFCC;}
   50%  {background: #CCCC99;}
   75% {background: #CC9999}
   100%{background:#CCCCFF}
 }

  @-webkit-keyframes colorchange  {
     0%   {background:#FFCCFF;}
     25%  {background: #FFFFCC;}
    50%  {background:  #CCCC99;}
    75% {background: #CC9999;}
    100%{background:#CCCCFF;}
 }
```

But I Want this change never stop ,How I can Do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `infinite` to your property.

[CSS3 animation Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp)

```
body {
margin-top:60px;
font-family: sans-serif;
animation: colorchange 50s infinite;
-webkit-animation: colorchange 50s infinite;
     }

@keyframes colorchange{
    0%   {background: #FFCCff;
   25%  {background: #FFFFCC;
   50%  {background: #CCCC99;
   75% {background: #CC9999
   100%{background:#CCCCFF
 }

  @-webkit-keyframes colorchange  {
     0%   {background:#FFCCFF;}
     25%  {background: #FFFFCC;}
    50%  {background:  #CCCC99;}
    75% {background: #CC9999}
    100%{background:#CCCCFF}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `infinite` option:

```
animation: colorchange 50s infinite;
-webkit-animation: colorchange 50s infinite;
```